# Find distribution function of the probability density function : $f(x) = \frac{\alpha}{x_0}(\frac{x_0}{x})^{\alpha+1}$ for $x > x_0 , \alpha>1$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

A continuous random variable $x$ has the following probability density function:

$f(x) = \frac{\alpha}{x_0}(\frac{x_0}{x})^{\alpha+1}$ for $x > x_0 , \alpha>1$

The distribution function and the mean of $x$ are given
respectively by:

A. $1 - (\frac{x}{x_0})^{\alpha} , \frac{\alpha - 1}{\alpha}x_0  $

B. $1 - (\frac{x}{x_0})^{-\alpha} , \frac{\alpha - 1}{\alpha}x_0  $

C. $1 - (\frac{x}{x_0})^{-\alpha} , \frac{\alpha}{\alpha - 1}x_0  $

D. $1 - (\frac{x}{x_0})^{\alpha} , \frac{\alpha}{\alpha - 1}x_0  $

I tried finding the Distribution function by integrating $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)$ but I don't know whether to treat $x_0$ as a variable or constant also if I should start the integration from $x_0$ or not.

Comment: $x_0$ should be treated as a constant, and indeed, integration starts from $x_0$.

Comment: This is called a (generalized) Pareto distribution.

Answer (score 2):

General formula for finding distribution function $F(x)$ when probability density function $f(x)$ is given:
$$F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x}f(x)\,dx\tag{1}\label{1}$$

Usually only non zero expression of density is given. In other words, in this case we have this probability density function:
$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
0,& x\leq x_0 \\
\frac{\alpha}{x_0}\left(\frac{x_0}{x}\right)^{\alpha+1},& x > x_0
\end{cases}\tag{2}\label{2}$$
Now $f(x)$ is defined on the whole $\mathbb{R}$ and thus we can use formula $(1)$. It has two parameters $x_0$ and $\alpha$ (they are constants). These parameters must satisfy inequalities $x_0>0$ and $\alpha>0$ since any probability density $f(x)$ has to satisfy these two properties:
$$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}: f(x) \geq 0$$
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\,dx = 1$$
Now lets use $(1)$ and $(2)$. Function $F(x)$ must be defined on the whole $\mathbb{R}$, but by looking at $(2)$ we see that the expression of $f(x)$ is different in these two regions: $x\leq x_0$ and $x>x_0$. That's why these two cases will be dealt separately.

If $x\leq x_0$ then
$$F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x}f(x)\,dx = \int_{-\infty}^{x}0\,dx = 0$$
If $x> x_0$ then
$$F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x}f(x)\,dx = \int_{-\infty}^{x_0}f(x)\,dx+\int_{x_0}^{x}f(x)\,dx = \int_{-\infty}^{x_0}0\,dx+\int_{x_0}^{x}\frac{\alpha}{x_0}\left(\frac{x_0}{x}\right)^{\alpha+1}\,dx=$$
$$= 0 + x_0^\alpha\frac{-1}{x^\alpha}\bigm|_{x_0}^{x} = 1-\left(\frac{x_0}{x}\right)^\alpha$$
So, we've got this distribution function:
$$F(x) =
\begin{cases}
0,& x\leq x_0 \\
1-\left(\frac{x_0}{x}\right)^\alpha,& x > x_0
\end{cases}\tag{3}\label{3}$$

Mathematical expectation is
$$\mathbb{E}X = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x\cdot f(x)\,dx = \int_{-\infty}^{x_0}x\cdot 0\,dx + \int_{x_0}^{\infty}x\cdot \frac{\alpha}{x_0}\left(\frac{x_0}{x}\right)^{\alpha+1}\,dx =$$
$$= 0 + \alpha x_0^\alpha\int_{x_0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^\alpha}\,dx = \begin{cases}
\infty,& 0<\alpha\leq 1 \\
\frac{\alpha x_0}{\alpha-1},& \alpha > 1
\end{cases}$$

**Bonus tip:**
While distribution function has to be defined on the whole $\mathbb{R}$ a probability density function doesn't have to be defined on the whole $\mathbb{R}$, but it still has to be defined *almost everywhere* on $\mathbb{R}$. It means that *the same* distribution (with *the same* parameters of [Pareto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution) distribution in this case) can have more than one different probability density function, but the distribution function will be the same. If $f(x)$ and $f_1(x)$ are different density functions of the same distribution then the equality $f_1(x)=f(x)$ must be true for *almost all* $x$ (it means $f_1(x)\neq f(x)$ only on a set $A$, whose [Lebesgue measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure), in other words *length* in this case, is zero).

For example,
$$f_1(x) =
\begin{cases}
0,& x< x_0 \\
1,& x= x_0 \\
\frac{\alpha}{x_0}\left(\frac{x_0}{x}\right)^{\alpha+1},& x > x_0
\end{cases}$$
is also a probability density function of Pareto distribution and using $(1)$ we'll still get the same distribution function $(3)$. The values of functions $f(x)$ and $f_1(x)$ differ only at one point $x=x_0$ (the *length* of one point is zero).